# Историческое объяснение форм именительного падежа множественного числа существительных

Tags: морфология, история

Каково историческое объяснение форм именительного падежа множественного числа существительных «платье» и «болото»:

Литературн.: платья

Диалектн: платьи

Литературн.: болота

Диалектн.: болоты?

Comment: Не по теме: здесь дают квалифицированные советы и ответы на вопросы..

Comment: о, это здорово. Было бы неплохо  получить ответ на вопрос или квалифицированный совет

Answer (score 3):

На протяжении многовековой истории русского языка система имени существительного развивалась в направлении к тому ее состоянию, какое мы находим в современном русском языке. От многотипности склонения, восходящей к общеиндоевропейской эпохе, от различия трех чисел и семи падежных форм, от большого разнообразия падежных окончаний не только в единственном, но и во множественном числе, от ярко выраженного различия твердой и мягкой разновидностей склонения система имени существительного шла по пути унификации типов склонения, утраты двойственного числа и звательной формы, по пути унификации падежных окончаний, особенно во множественном числе, по пути сближения твердой и мягкой разновидностей склонений.

Если в ед.ч. тенденция к преодолению синонимии флексий реализовалась в направлении сближения склонения существительных одного рода, то во мн.ч. эта грамматическая тенденция должна была привести к полной унификации(единообразию) типов склонения, что было связано с нивелировкой родовых различий во мн.ч.
В процессе унификации форм И.-В.п. решающую роль сыграла тенденция к объединению флексий обоихъ падежей у существительных муж.р., т.к. у существительных жен.р. и ср.р. И.-В.п. совпадали изначально. В результате в И.-В.п. устанавливаются флексии -ы (-и); -а (-я): страны, земли, столы, гости.

В древнерусском языке было не 2 числа, как в современном русском , а три. Кроме единственного. и множественного было ещё и двойственное число. Оно употреблялось в строго определенных случаях:

а) когда речь шла о двух предметах (или лицах), причем количество могло быть и не указано: тѣ грамотѣ (Новгор. гр.);

б) когда существительное обозначало парные предметы, например: рога (одного животного), рукава, берега, края (начало и конец), руцѣ, нозѣ (у одного человека), очи, уши (у одного существа), плечи (одного человека). Этих предметов могло быть и много, и тогда употреблялось множественное число: рози, берези, рукы, ногы, очеса, ушеса, плеча.

Если в единственном и множественном числе существительные разных древних типов склонения имели разные окончания в одном и том же падеже, то в двойственном эти разные окончания, и то не в полной мере, были лишь в имен.-вин. пад. (ср.: стола, селэ, поли, сестрэ, земли, сыны, кости, колеси, матери и т. д.).

Утрата двойственного числа в древнерусском языке отражается в памятниках с XIII в., причем это находит свое выражение в замене форм двойственного числа формами множественного числа. Как видно, такая замена сначала возникала там, где существительное, которое должно было быть по древним нормам употреблено в двойственном числе, не имело при себе числительного два. Так, в Духовном завещании Климента новгородца XIII в. встречается на свои роукы вместо на свои роуцэ (ибо речь идет о двух руках); в рижской грамоте 1300 г.: и тоу порты съ него снемъ за шию оковалъ и р у к и и н о г ы (вместо руцэ и нозэ). Если же при подобном существительном стояло числительное два, то двойственное число удерживалось дольше: взя два города галичьскыи (Ипат. лет.)

Если говорить о формах имен.-вин.-зват. пад., то здесь, вероятно, рано исчезла форма на -э или -и у слов среднего рода с основой на ŏ заменивщись формой на -а под влиянием слов мужского рода того же типа склонения, например: даю два села (Дух. Клим, новг.), два лэта (Новг. лет.) и др. Это, без сомнения, объясняется тем, что слова мужского и среднего рода с основой на ŏ имели одинаковые формы в единственном числе и в косвенных падежах двойственного числа.

Таким образом, в истории русского языка двойственное число исчезло, однако определенные, а в ряде случаев достаточно заметные, следы, указывающие на наличие этих форм в прошлом, остались в русском языке и **диалектах.**

**Формы именительного падежа множественного числа плечи, колени, уши, очи исторически восходят к формам двойственного числа. т.е. формы двойственного числа стали передавать значение множественности. Старые формы множественного числа плеча, колена, ушеса, очеса были вытеснены.** В то же время колебания в выборе форм наблюдались в языке довольно долго. Например, у Пушкина в «Евгении Онегине»: …И первым снегом с кровли бани умыть лицо, плеча и грудь. У Тургенева в романе «Отцы и дети»: … Платок скатился с её головы на плеча.

В современном русском языке такие формы не употребляются. Названные выше лексемы в русском языке сохранили форму двойственного числа только в именительном и винительном падежах. В украинском языке сохранились и другие формы этих существительных, например, в творительном падеже: плечима, очима. В польском языке формы двойственного числа сохранили три падежа.

К формам именительного и винительного падежей двойственного числа восходит также **окончание -А в именительном падеже множественного числа имён существительных мужского рода**: рукава´, глаза´, берега´, бока´, рога´ (**бывшие формы имён существительных именительного падежа двойственного числа стали осмысляться как существительные множественного числа); и по аналогии с ними возникли леса´, города´, дома´, хотя эти существительные отнюдь не обозначают пар**

В сочетаниях типа два попа, два часа формы попа, часа с утратой двойственного числа „уже не вызывали представления о двойственном числе, но они не вызывали представления и о множественном (результатом этого была бы замена их формами множественного числа). Потеряв категорию числа, **эти формы, естественно, сблизились с тождественными с ними формами родительного единственного ... Это повело к обшей замене формой родительного падежа единственного числа формы двойственного числа, потерявшей свое значение, и там, где форма двойственного числа по звуку не была тождественна с формой родительного падежа"** (А. А. Шахматов. Историческая морфология.— С. 213).

Именно поэтому в русском языке возникло не только два села вместо древнего дъв-Ь сел-к, где подверглось изменению как числительное, так и существительное, но и две рыбы вместо дъвэ рыбэ И конечно, в сочетаниях два села, две рыбы формы села, рыбы — это уже действительно формы род, пад. ед. ч. от село, рыба: они не только осознаются таковыми, как это случилось с формой стола в два стола, но и по происхождению являются формами род. пад.

Так что были  платьи, болоты - остаток двойственного ч.(теперь только в диалектах), стали  платья, болота -слились с родит.п.ед.ч.(два платья, два болота)

Comment: @ Людмила,все очень интересно, только не могли бы вы объяснить, почему в словах две рыбы, два села - это исконно род.пад,. а не двойственное число. Я не очень поняла.

Comment: Формы (нет) стола, коня, села, моря являются исконными, т.к. относились к склонению на *о И. дроугъ село конь поле Р. дроуга села коня поля.  Оно не подвергалось изменениям. В склонении на *a в большинстве случаев новые формы появляются в результате взаимодействия твердого и мягкого вариантов: (нет) земли новая, она возникла  в результате воздействия твердого варианта на мягкий, как (нет) жены.Рыба-твёрдый вариант, он исконный- с основ. на  * -ā , не изменялся.  И. жена кънига рыба Р. жены кънигы рыбы

Comment: А в двойств.ч было в.  Р.п. - рыбоу     селоу, так что это никак не остаток двойственного

Comment: @Людмла,спасибо, понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Это попытка дать совет (слишком обширный для комментария).

1) Если это учебное задание, попытайтесь найти ответ в рекомендованной литературе.

2) Если это исследовательский вопрос, попытайтесь найти ответ в профессиональной литературе. Для начала можно воспользоваться поисковиками. [Здесь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=by2YCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0ury4-uXXAhWDalAKHYnoDJEQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%22&f=false), например, можно найти употребление слова "платьи" и по сноске к этому слову — предполагаемое объяснение (не очень уверенное, поэтому желательно продолжить поиски).